# How can I try SNMP on my local machine?

Tags: networking, snmp, mib

For a client I have to develop a database connection which uses SNMP responses as input.

I want to try to parse these reponses; but I do not know how to set up SNMP on my local machine only. In other words: I want to query my own machine for its MIB info.

I have already done:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snmp snmp-mibs-downloader
# edit /etc/snmp/snmp.conf and uncomment "mibs :"
```

How can I query my own local machine?

I found this oneliner, but it gives me a time-out:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c tes90w90wer -O e 127.0.0.1
```

Note that I did not define `tes90w90wer` so maybe that is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `-c public` to get the results you are after. In short:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -O e 127.0.0.1
```

If you then want full access to the MIB tree, you should also **uncomment** the following line in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`:

```
# rocommunity public  localhost
```